# Android animation crashes with bitmap size exceeds VM budget

Tags: android

I have an animation of 25 frames, in compressed jpeg, less then 2mb in total.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:oneshot="true">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/y1" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/y2" android:duration="50" />
     ...

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/mouse" android:duration="50" />

</animation-list>
```

Yet when I try to play it

```
    iv.setBackgroundResource( R.anim.yawn );
    AnimationDrawable anim = (AnimationDrawable)iv.getBackground();
    anim.start();
```

it crashed with bitmap size exceeds VM budget.

Any ideas what can I do?

Thanks!

Comment: What are the dimensions of the images?

Comment: Android could probably handle 4 frames of that size, but not much more. You have to think about an entirely different approach, like using a video player or creating an animation with sprites.

Comment: Hmm... really don't want to use the video player, besides I have only 25 frames. what do you think, if I'd split this one animation into, say, 2 or 3 ?

Comment: nope, splitting doesn't seem to work, same error.

Answer (score 0):

What if just decrease "duty cycle"... Once I had error with OutOfMemory working with images, but Somethibg like .... helped me.... Code is above...

```
      private void unbindDrawables(View view) {
 if (view.getBackground() != null) {
 view.getBackground().setCallback(null);
 }
 if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
     for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
     unbindDrawables(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));
     }
 ((ViewGroup) view).removeAllViews();
 }
```

}